# How should I implement a custom form field type only for display accepting several formats

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

In my forms I need a field to only display data. No editing will be done on this data so I feel it's not enough to set read_only on a text field. The idea is to create  custom form field type that would accept different formats as the value (ex. DateTime, String).

The output would be somethink like

```
<div>
    <label>My Label</label>
    My value
</div>
```

I've been looking into the docs and also the code of the predefined field types but couldn't make out how to go on :-(

I'm not looking for the complete code, only need directions...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, thanks to another thread on Stackoverflow, I went with DataTransformer (see the [Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)).

This way I add the field as a text type and add a custom DataTransformer to the FormBuilder which will convert the data to the type I need.

If anyone is interested in it I will post the code.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion: If this is for display only, then it's not form data and therefore has no business being implemented as a `Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType`

Perhaps you can give some more detail about exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi Peter,Parts of my forms are just for information while other parts are for editing. For example, when editing user data there is no use in editing the last log in of the user... it should only be displayed.

Comment: I agree. You should remove any "display-only" fields from the form type. Instead pass these values to the template directly from the controller.

Comment: So then just pass that data (user's last login or whatever) directly to the view and render it there. There's no value and only headaches to come from trying to bake it into the form type.

Comment: As it is something common (at least for me) I'd like to have it "automatized" via Type class. Also, even if its not editable, it is part of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use [form events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html). Read this example in official docs.

Comment: Hi Smoremo, I couldn't find how that could help me... Please give some more details. Thanks.